# VBA Colouring Celldata between Specified Values

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub einfarben()
Worksheets("2_Basisdata").Activate
Dim Startvalue As Variant
Dim Endvalue As Variant
Application.InputBox("startvalue") = Startvalue
Application.InputBox("endvalue") = Endvalue
Dim C As Range
Dim rng As Range
rng = Range("B2;J13")
For Each C In rng
On Error Resume Next
If Startvalue < C And C < Endvalue Then
   C.Font.ColorIndex = 4
End If
Next C
End Sub
```

My Problem: I got Several Runtime Errors.
The Holdingmarker Pops up at the First Application.Inputbox
My Goal is to achieve that the Cells where the Value is between Start and End Changing to green..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to switch the right hand side and the left hand sides of the two statements involving `InputBox`. The first one should read

```
Startvalue = Val(InputBox("start value"))
```

Similarly for the next line. There doesn't seem to be much point in using `Application.InputBox` here so I dropped the `Application`.  I added `Val` to convert the input strings to numbers.

Also, you need to use `Set` when you assign a range to a range variable:

Set rng = Range("B2:J13")

Comment: I would also get rid of the `On Error Resume Next` line

Comment: @scottcraner Good point. I thought of mentioning that but decided to focus on the actual syntax errors. There is obviously a lot of room for improvement in that code.